# How to error check Python Statistics mode function?

Tags: python, mode

There is a question similar to this existing but does not quite fit my situation.  I'm using Python 3.4 and want to use the mode function of the statistics module, however when there is not a mode python terminates program and gives me an error.  Is there an if statement I could write to check if there are duplicates in my list, and if not display a print message before the mode function begins, and prevent the mode function from running?
So far I have:

```
    UserNumbers=input("Enter number sequence separated by spaces: ")
    nums = [int(i) for i in UserNumbers.split()]
    Average = mean(nums)
    print ("The mean is ", Average)
    Middle = median(nums)
    print ("The median is ", Middle)
    Most = mode(nums)
    print ("The mode is ", Most)
```

I am a beginner so it's a bit hard to convey my problem properly, please excuse incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check with a set:

```
if len(set(nums)) == len(nums)
```

If you have dups the length of the set will be shorter than the length of your list.

```
if len(set(nums)) != len(nums): # check different lengths, if different we have dups 
    print ("The mode is ", Most)
    Most = mode(nums)
else:      # else both are the  same size so no dups, just print 
    print("No duplicates in nums")
```

Set cannot have duplicate items:

```
In [1]: nums =[1,2,3,4,1]

In [2]: nums
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

In [3]: set(nums)
Out[3]: {1, 2, 3, 4} # sets cannot have duplicate items

In [4]: len(set(nums)) == len(nums) # set = len 4, nums = len 5
Out[4]: False
```

Comment: I changed the logic, I thought you wanted to not run the Mode function if there were dups, now it will only run it there are dups and ignore otherwise

Comment: Using a try-except block is the proper way to deal with potential malformed data errors and is also more performant assuming errors are infrequent. Ask for forgiveness, not permission.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html), `If data is empty, or if there is not exactly one most common value, StatisticsError is raised`. Thus, simply having duplicates in the list will not ensure that there is a mode.

A preferred solution would be to use the exception mechanism, e.g.:

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,8,9]
try:
    m = mode(nums)
except StatisticsError:
    print ("No unique mode found")
```

Answer (score 4):

A common coding style in Python is that it's [easier to ask for forgiveness than permission](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). You should use a [try-except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block:

```
from statistics import mode, StatisticsError

try:
  print("The mode is " + mode(nums))
except StatisticsError:
  print("There is no mode!")
```

A few other notes:

- In Python, common style is to use `snake_case` rather than `camelCase` for variables, though `PascalCase` is commonly used for classes.
- Just as in Java and other languages, typically variables are `lowercase` while classes are `Uppercase`.

Comment: Whoops, because the OP preceded the parens with a space, I thought they were using the print keyword. That explains how it worked in Python 3.

Comment: Probably none, but it means you iterate over the entire list and duplicate at least part if it in memory every time that code is executed. Why do all that when `statistics.mode` will tell you if there's a problem anyways? Better to just let it do the work and handle the error case.

Answer (score 1):

If more than one item is duplicated the same number of times, the `len(set(list)) != len(list)` check will not suffice.